# Left align in math environment with every element over each other

Tags: math-mode, align

I would like the elements in my math environment to be left aligned, so that each element stands over each other, like in the given example below. I have managed it using `\hspace` and `\qquad`, but thought there is a more elegant way to do this. Can anyone suggest a better solution?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\gamma(0)=\quad\alpha_1\gamma(1)\hspace{27pt}+\quad\alpha_2\gamma(2)\hspace{27pt}+\quad\dots\quad+\quad\alpha_p\gamma(p)\quad+\quad\sigma^2 \\
&\gamma(1)=\quad\alpha_1\gamma(0)\hspace{27pt}+\quad\alpha_2\gamma(1)\hspace{27pt}+\quad\dots\quad+\quad\alpha_p\gamma(p-1) \\
&\vdots \\
&\gamma(p)=\quad\alpha_1\gamma(p-1)\quad+\quad\alpha_2\gamma(p-2)\quad+\quad\dots\quad+\quad\alpha_p\gamma(0)

\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wasn't my answer good enough? `:(`

Comment: I think you adapted your answer to that by Thorsten Donig, didn't you? So I suggest his war slightly better.

Comment: No. I just moved some curly brackets in order to remove the ampersands. I have a feeling that Thorsten took my code and used it. (At least all of his code--minus the ampersands--in the `aligned` environment is exactly the same as mine, and I posted mine first.) P.S. I haven't got any problem with Thorsten's answer at all.

Comment: Are you sure he copied your code?

Comment: No. As I said, I _think_ he did.

Comment: @RStudent Hey Rstudent, I saw a question of yours on stackoverflow about the package midasr, and I was wondering if I could get your help on a small error I'm facing; Is there anyway I could contact you by email or otherwise? (I would have commented this comment on the relevant question on SO but my reputation was not high enough)

Comment: Ok, send me an email to rstudent@outlook.de...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to keep one single equation number, you can use the `alignedat` environment inside `equation`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}  % loads »amsmath«

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    \begin{alignedat}{5}
      \gamma(0) &= \alpha_1\gamma(1) &&+ \alpha_2\gamma(2) &&+ \cdots &&+ \alpha_p\gamma(p)&&+ \sigma^2 \\
      \gamma(1) &= \alpha_1\gamma(0) &&+ \alpha_2\gamma(1) &&+ \cdots &&+ \alpha_p\gamma(p-1) \\
      &\vdotswithin{=} \\
      \gamma(p) &= \alpha_1\gamma(p-1)&&+ \alpha_2\gamma(p-2) &&+ \cdots &&+\alpha_p\gamma(0)
    \end{alignedat}
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: Why load [`fontenc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontenc)?

Comment: Probably, but the other answer was posted earlier. Unfortunately cannot accept two answers but upvote...

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: I simply always load it. Just a habit when writing in another language than English and for better font quality. Not mandatory here.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a possible solution if no equation number is required:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{4}
  \gamma(0) &= \alpha_1\gamma(1)   &&+ \alpha_2\gamma(2)   &&+ \dots + \alpha_p\gamma(p)  &&+ \sigma^2 \\
  \gamma(1) &= \alpha_1\gamma(0)   &&+ \alpha_2\gamma(1)   &&+ \dots + \alpha_p\gamma(p-1)&&           \\
            &\vdotswithin{=} \\
  \gamma(p) &= \alpha_1\gamma(p-1) &&+ \alpha_2\gamma(p-2) &&+ \dots + \alpha_p\gamma(0)  &&
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

If the centered equation number is indeed required, use an `equation`--`alignedat` combination, as in [Thorsten's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/159653/15874).

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is definitely the way to go, but if ever you're stuck on a desert island and you don't have the `amsmath` package, an `array` environment can do *some* of the work- there are deficiencies (such as the alignment of the `\vdots` and the need for extra `{}`), but it does get some of the job done.

[image: screenshot]

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: on}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{array}{r@{}l@{}l@{}l@{}l@{}l@{}l@{}}
        \gamma(0) & {}=\alpha_1\gamma(1)    & {}+\alpha_2\gamma(2)   & {}+{}\cdots {} &   & {}+\alpha_p\gamma(p)   & {}+\sigma^2 \\
        \gamma(1) & {} =\alpha_1\gamma(0)   & {}+\alpha_2\gamma(1)   & {}+{}\cdots {} &   & {}+\alpha_p\gamma(p-1) &             \\
                  & \vdots                  &                        &                &   &                        &             \\
        \gamma(p) & {} =\alpha_1\gamma(p-1) & {}+\alpha_2\gamma(p-2) & {}+{}\cdots {} &   & {}+\alpha_p\gamma(0)   &
    \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: The alignment of the plusses are wrong. Also, the horizontal dots should be `\cdots` and the `\vdots` is also aligned wrong.

Answer (score 2):

This is using the `tabstackengine` package, which extends the `stackengine` package by adding tabbing capability.

The spacing between columns is set by `\setstacktabbedgap{1em}`.  The interline spacing by `\setstackgap{L}{1.4\baselineskip}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\setstackgap{L}{1.4\baselineskip}
\setstacktabbedgap{1em}
\tabbedCenterstack[l]{%
\gamma(0)&=\alpha_1\gamma(1)&+\alpha_2\gamma(2)&+&\dots&+\alpha_p\gamma(p)&+\sigma^2 \\
\gamma(1)&=\alpha_1\gamma(0)&+\alpha_2\gamma(1)&+&\dots&+\alpha_p\gamma(p-1)& \\
\protect\raisebox{-2.5pt}{\vdots}&&&&&& \\
\gamma(p)&=\alpha_1\gamma(p-1)&+\alpha_2\gamma(p-2)&+&\dots&+\alpha_p\gamma(0)&
}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If one wanted the `\vdots` under the equal sign, the third row of the tabbed stack could be made as

```
&\,\raisebox{-2.5pt}{\vdots}&&&&& \\
```

to achieve a result that looks like

[image]

Comment: Your suggestion brings the desired output but I would prefer not using additional package.

Comment: @JohnnyB  Understood.  It is always a trade-off.  I eliminated `amsmath` from my answer, but you will most likely employ it for your other math needs.

Comment: The aligment points and the dots are wrong.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg If you  mean the `\vdots` are out of vertical kilter, I see that and have fixed it.  What else to you mean by "alignment points"?  Do you mean that the `...` should be centered between the two plus signs?  I fixed that, too.

Comment: I think it looked different when I posted the previous comment; now it is only the `\vdots`. Shouldn't they be aligned under `=` as in Thorsten's and my answers?

Answer (score 2):

If you feel brave enough (and have recently read Ch. 22 of the TeXbook) you can always try doing it the plain TeX way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\vcenter{\openup6pt\halign{\hfil$\gamma(#)={}$&$#$\hfil &&${}+#\hfil$\cr
0 & \alpha_1\gamma(1) & \alpha_2\gamma(2) & \cdots & \alpha_p\gamma(p) & \sigma^2 \cr
1 & \alpha_1\gamma(0) & \alpha_2\gamma(1) & \cdots & \alpha_p\gamma(p-1)\cr
\omit \hfil$\vdots$\enspace\cr
p & \alpha_1\gamma(p-1) & \alpha_2\gamma(p-2) & \cdots & \alpha_p\gamma(0)\cr
}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Notice how you can move repeated parts of the display into the preamble, and that you can use `\omit` to omit the boiler plate where you don't want it. [image]

Comment: Really cool solution!